# Can't find the javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my website but when I click, it doesn't respond. But the other button works. The location of the button where i got the error(which it doesn't respond to my click) is a bootstrap dialog. But the other bootstrap dialog works fine. May I have any suggestions or solutions ?

Following is the html code

```
<button type="button" class="btncanceldocument btn btn-warning"  >
    Cancel Document
</button>
```

And this is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btncanceldocument').click(function () {
        alert("Say hello");
    });
});
```

Is there something wrong with it? if not i think the problem is on other javascript code. So how can i find the problem using my browser? or does my browser print some error? I have lots of javascript code on this file. I can't find the problem or error?

Comment: Why are you identifying by class and not by id?

Comment: Document ready is not fired when a modal is open. You need to attach the event on open modal event

Comment: but that code works on the other html file @MarcosPérezGude but in this html file it doesnt work. so i know that the problem is on other javascript code on this file. but i cant find it. can i debug the html using a browser? if yes. how?

Comment: and how can i attach the event on open modal event @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: Yes , you can debug with your browser. Try it, it's easy and funny. The other code works, but we can't see it. You need to provide a working example. Maybe you need to read the help rules of stackoverflow. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it's important you read that and came back to provide a working example reproducing the issue.

Comment: See also: how to debug in firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Tools/Debugger (the best webdeveloper tools actually)

Comment: try the different format like this :

$(document).on('click','.btncanceldocument',function(){ // code here } });

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, most browsers have a built in debugging tool. My personal favourite is Chrome.

If you right-click anywhere on your page then choose 'inspect' you will open it.

Here is a link that will help you - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en

It's worth spending some time learning about that as it will save you in the long run.

When you open the debug you will be able to run JS code in the console, so you can manually fire your click using:

```
 $('.btncanceldocument').click();
```

Then you will be able to make sure your code is working. If clicking with your mouse isn't working sometimes it could be as the button is actually behind a transparent element.

In the debug tool you are also able to select HTML elements so you can see if something is blocking the button. A quick tip for checking this is if you increase the CSS z-index property on the button to a large value e.g. '9999999999999' . This will bring the button 'above' the other content of the page.

Hopefully this helps,

Pete

Comment: This not provide an answer to the question. You are teaching to debug in browsers. With a link that goes to a reference it's sufficient in a comment.

Comment: She specifically asks ' how can i find the problem using my browser ' and then you also give her a link to FF debug so what are you talking about.

Comment: This is clearly offtopic in stackoverflow, it's because you can leave a comment with a link and mark to close as offtopic, for example, but don't provide an offtopic answer to an offtopic question. Read the help of stackoverflow.